# Uncaught Error: Module name "aaa_bbb_1_pb" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, node-modules

I am trying to load protobuf js file using require but I am getting following exception on console.

```
02-21 11:18:06.445 9130-9130/com.p.protoextensiontest I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(5)] "Uncaught Error: Module name "js/proto/data_main_1_pb" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/require.js (5)
"Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function p(){
```

Here is my code of index.js

```
var proto = require('js/proto/aaa_bbb_1_pb');

function onCreate(){
    console.log("in onCreate");
    parseProto();
}
function parseProto(){
    var name = proto.person.personName;
}
```

Here is my index.html

```
<head>
    <title> Testing proto extension</title>
    <script src="js/require.js"></script>
    <script src="js/google-protobuf.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <button type="button"  onclick="onCreate()"> Create Data</button> <br/> 
</body>
```

I am newbie on javascript and node.js. Please provide any reference.

Answer (score 2):

The module you show in `index.js` is in the CommonJS format. It does not have a wrapper and makes `require` calls that contain a single string argument.

However, you are using RequireJS to load it. RequireJS is an AMD module loader, not a CommonJS module loader. You don't have to completely rewrite your `require` calls to use the AMD  format (a `require` call with an array of dependencies and a callback) but you have to at least wrap your module's code in a `define` call, like this:

```
define(function (require) {
  var proto = require('js/proto/aaa_bbb_1_pb');

  function onCreate(){
      console.log("in onCreate");
      parseProto();
  }

  function parseProto(){
      var name = proto.person.personName;
  }
}
```

---

Note that `onclick=onCreate()` still won't work. One of the goals of using modules is to avoid putting everything in the global space. So `onCreate` is not accessible to `onclick`. The minimal way to make it accessible would be to add `window.onCreate = onCreate` after your definition of the function but I do not recommend this. You should either add an exported function that you can call at initialization with the button object and that will call `addEventListener("click", onCreate)`, or the module could search for a specific element on the page (by ID, class name, whatever) and call `addEventListener("click", onCreate)`.